# bootstrap-table tamaño input buscar

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código con una tabla bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table id="tabla-servicios" class="table">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
   $tabla.bootstrapTable({
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        search:true
    });
```

Lo que quiero es acortar el tamaño del input search, cómo puedo lograr eso?

[image: bootstap table]

Comment: Que versión de bootstrap y bootstrapTable estas utilizando? replique tu codigo y el input no se ve tan grande como en tu imagen

Comment: BT 1.14.2 y bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: La estructura del Bootstrap está bien planteada. Lo que me lleva a pensar que el problema o bien es que no has cargado bien la librería (por lo que los **col** no estarían haciendo nada) o bien que el problema lo tienes en otro punto del **HTML**. ¿Podrías ponernos el **HTML** completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer al usar la **versión 3.3.7** de `Bootstrap` por defecto el input toma el ancho de un 100%, por lo que sólo deberías sobre escribir ese `width` con

```
width: valor
```

Con un 50% quedaría algo así

```js
$('#tabla-servicios').bootstrapTable({
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        search:true
    });
```

```css
.search{
  width:50%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table id="tabla-servicios" class="table">
          <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item ID</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>$1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>$2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas

Comment: eso funcionó muchas gracias